# JQGrid Grouping array data and sorting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grouping, sorting

I am using JQgrid for display my data with grouping and sorting.
When my page is loaded, it does not show grouping at all.
But, it works fine after i do sorting on column, it displays grouping. I want grouping displayed on my page load.
Also i am confusing with css and js files used. Below is my code. Please help me.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/js/src/css/ui.multiselect.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/basic/grid.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/jqModal.css" />

 <style type="text">
        html, body {
        margin: 0;            /* Remove body margin/padding */
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;    /* Remove scroll bars on browser window */
        font-size: 75%;
        }
    </style> 

<!--<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<script src="js/jquery.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/src/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/src/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.contextMenu.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#list4").jGrid.no_legacy_api = true; 
    </script>

<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function(){ 
  $("#list4").jqGrid({

                        data: mydata,
                        datatype: "local",
                        height: 'auto',
                       colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
                       colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, 
                       {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"}, 
                       {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true}, 
                       {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number", editable:true}, 
                 {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable:true}, 
                 {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
                 {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} ],
                                pager: '#pager',
                                rowNum:30,
                                rowList:[10,20,30],                               
                                loadonce: true,
            sortable:true, 
                                viewrecords: true,                                
                                imgpath: "themes/basic/images",
                               caption: "Grouping Array Data",
                               sortname: 'name',
                               grouping:true, 
        groupingView : { groupField : ['name'], groupColumnShow : [true],groupOrder : ['asc'],groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>', '{0}'] },
        groupDataSorted : true,
         plusicon: 'bullet_toggle_plus',
    minusicon: 'bullet_toggle_minus'
        //Required for client side sorting
//    loadonce: true,

    }    
            );


   var mydata = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} , 
   {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"21.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"12",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"13",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"15",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"16",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"18",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"19",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
   {id:"21",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
   {id:"22",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
   {id:"23",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
    {id:"24",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
    {id:"25",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
    {id:"26",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
    {id:"27",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
    {id:"28",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
    {id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"} ];


        for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
            jQuery("#list4").addRowData(i, mydata[i]);              
            }//function
    );//ready
 $("#list4").jqGrid().setGridParam({sortname: 'Date,', sortorder: 
'asc'}).trigger("reloadGrid");    

</script>
</head>

<body>

This is table

<table id="list4">

</table>

<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;">

</div>

This is table

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer of my question itself.
Array declaration and manipulation loop should be inside of anonymous function jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}), and not outside of it. This way it will be executed after jqQrid initialization and not before.